# SQL: Year of last occurence?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find the last time, the day and year combination has happened.
So, I have long list of date and I need output with last occurring year.

For example,
Suppose, 31/12/2018 has not happened in 2018, so I want 31/12/2017 as output?

```
Table:
Dates
01/03/2013
01/09/2012
01/03/2013
01/06/2011
03/03/2009
11/07/2011
01/03/2023
01/05/2021

Output:
01/03/2018
01/09/2018
01/03/2018
01/06/2018
03/03/2018
11/07/2018
01/03/2017
01/05/2017
```

Comment: sample data will help

Comment: Help us help you - please [edit] your post and share the table's structure, sample data and the result you'd like to get for it.

Comment: god helps those who helps themselves!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: whats the logic???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

```
select t2.*,
       (case when month(col) < month(current_date) or
                  (month(col) < month(current_date) and day(col) <= day(current_date))
             then year(current_date)
             else 1 + year(current_date)
        end)
from table2 t2;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `T-SQL ISDATE` function ([docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) combined with a brute force approach?

**In Short:**
Loop over years from current year (descending order) and ask if the date (combines with current iteration year) is a valid date? If not - proceed (by decreasing year value).